# PLSQL Function used in where clause - Performance Issue

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a query which performs quite ok for a limited number of ROWNUMS but once it exceeds this particular ROWNUM it performs very miserable.

Below is the query:

`SELECT  p.col1,pv.col1
  FROM  tab1 p, tab2 tv, tab3 pv
  WHERE myFunc(pv.col1) = 1
  AND tv.col1 = pv.col1
  AND p.col1 = tv.col2
  AND ROWNUM < 4500`

All these tables have huge (more than a million) records.

The above query executes at a very decent speed.

If ROWNUM < 5000 or more then it takes quite a lot of time.

Is there any way I can improve the performance of the above query?

Comment: Are the columns you've joined indexed on all three tables?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what `myFunc` does.

Comment: You should examine (and add into your question) the EXPLAIN PLAN for both the statement with `ROWNUM<1000` and the statement with `ROWNUM<10000`. Are they different, and how? The function might be called early in the plan, or late, and this may affect the performance. Alternatively, the function may have nothing to do with the performance problem.

Comment: The columns are indexed on the tables.

Comment: <code>myFunc</code> has around 7-8 SELECT queries based on the passed in param and returns 0 or 1 based on certain criteria.

Comment: Could this be a tmp space problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that there is indexes on each join columns on each table, and after that, you can use functional indexes, see for example : http://techonthenet.com/oracle/indexes.php